# Print a newline every n characters

Tags: c++

I'm trying to print an array of characters, but I would like to print a newline after a fixed number of characters. So far I only can print a newline after the first fixed amount of characters are read. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
    for ( int i = 0; i < (m_nWidth*m_nHeight); i++) {
        if (i != m_nWidth)
            cout << pMyPointer[i];
        else
        {
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if( i % n == 0 && i != 0 ) printf("\n");
```

where `n` is the number of characters between newlines.

---

Edit:
In full context:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const int n = 5;
    const std::string str("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
    for (int i=0 ; i<str.size() ; ++i)
    {
        if (i%n == 0 && i != 0)
            std::cout << '\n';
        std::cout << str[i];
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! the problem is that now after each newline, the next character to be printed is missing eg - line is: abcdefg. If n = 4, then when i run the code i get abcd'\n'fg- how can i solve that now?

Comment: This prints the first line with N+1 characters. How would you suggest avoiding that?

Comment: Print the character after the `if()` block. Updated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the module operator:

```
if(i % n == 0)
 printf("\n");
```